# ERROR Unable to resolve dependency for ':app @debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath' Could not resolve project :SimpleCommons

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
```

':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project
   :SimpleCommons
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for 
   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project 
    :SimpleCommons
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
    not resolve project :SimpleCommons

**I've tried to change `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` but this not working and other errors**

This is that errors.

```
ERROR: Library projects cannot set applicationId
ERROR: Library projects cannot set applicationIdSuffix
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :SimpleCommons
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :SimpleCommons
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :SimpleCommons
```

How to solve this?